# Tic-Tac-Toe game: How do I get enum to print blank space

Tags: java, enums

One of my assignments for class is to use the shell the instructor provided and make the tic tac toe game. I am not allowed to change any function signatures or remove any of the instructor's code. We have not learned how to do arrays, so this assignment does not use them. The board is printed after every turn, where ever there is the MARKER.EMPTY, it should have an empty space. However I whenever I print it the marker "EMPTY" is printed. I apologize in advanced as my code is very messy, I am in my first programming class.

It should look like

X |  | O

Instead its printing like

X | EMPTY | O

I would appreciate any answers. This is the last part of the assignment that I can't figure out. Thank you for any help.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class TicTacToe
{

public enum Marker
{
    EMPTY,
    X,
    O
};

private static Marker position1 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position2 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position3 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position4 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position5 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position6 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position7 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position8 = Marker.EMPTY;
private static Marker position9 = Marker.EMPTY;

private static Marker turn = Marker.X;

public static void main(String[]args)
{
Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
printExampleboard();
for (int x = 0;x<10;x++)
    {
    if (hasWon(Marker.X) == true)
    {
    System.out.println("Player X has won!");
    System.exit(0);
    }
    if (hasWon(Marker.O) == true)
    {
    System.out.println("Player O has won!");
    System.exit(0);
    }
    boolean tie = isTie();
    if (tie == true)
        {
        System.out.println("This game is a tie!");
        }   
    else
    {
    if (x%2 == 1)
        {
        boolean oinput = true;
        System.out.println("Player O, please enter a position to play");
        while (oinput == true)
            {
            turn = Marker.O;
            int pos = scan.nextInt();
            if (isValidMove(pos) == true)
                {
                markTheBoard(turn, pos);
                printBoard();
                oinput = false;
                }
            else 
                {
                System.out.println("Position " + pos + " is already occupied or an invalid , please pick another position."); 
                }
            }
        }
    else
        {
        boolean input = true;
        System.out.println("Player X, please enter a position to play");
        while (input == true)
            {
            turn = Marker.X;
            int pos = scan.nextInt();
            if (isValidMove(pos) == true)
                {
                markTheBoard(turn, pos);
                printBoard();
                input = false;
                }
            else 
                {
                System.out.println("Position " + pos + " is already occupied or an invalid , please pick another position."); 
                }
            }
        }
    }   
    }


}

/**
  * This function returns true if the spot is empty, false if not. boolean
  */
public static boolean isValidMove(int pos)
{
    if (pos>0 && pos <10)
        {
        Marker m = Marker.EMPTY;
        switch(pos)
            {
            case 1: 
                {
                m = position1; 
                break;
                }
            case 2: 
                {
                m = position2; 
                break;
                }
            case 3: 
                {
                m = position3; 
                break;
                }
            case 4: 
                {
                m = position4; 
                break;
                }
            case 5: 
                {
                m = position5; 
                break;
                }
            case 6: 
                {
                m = position6; 
                break;
                }
            case 7: 
                {
                m = position7; 
                }
                break;
            case 8: 
                {
                m = position8; 
                break;
                }
            case 9: 
                {
                m = position9; 
                break;
                }
            }
                if (m == Marker.EMPTY)
                    {
                    return true;
                    }
                    else 
                    {
                    return false;
                    }
        }
    else 
        {

        return false;
        }   
}

public static void printExampleboard()
{
    System.out.println("We are about to play Tic Tac Toe, when asked to enter a position,\nplease refer to the below map:");
    for (int x = 0; x < 9; x+=3)
    {
    System.out.println("-------------");
    System.out.println("| " + (x + 1) + " | " + (x + 2) + " | "+ (x + 3) + " |");
    }
    System.out.println("-------------");
}
/**
 * This method will print the board as shown in the above example.
 */
public static void printBoard()
{
System.out.println("-------------");
System.out.println("| " + position1 + " | " + position2 + " | " + position3 + " | ");
System.out.println("-------------");
System.out.println("| " + position4 + " | " + position5 + " | " + position6 + " | ");
System.out.println("-------------");
System.out.println("| " + position7 + " | " + position8 + " | " + position9 + " | ");
System.out.println("-------------");    
}

/**
 * Checks if a particular player has won.
 * 
 * @param m The player to check
 * @return true if the player won, false if not boolean
 */
public static boolean hasWon(Marker m)
{
if ((position1 == m && position2 == m && position3 == m) ||(position4 == m && position5 == m && position6 == m) ||
    (position7 == m && position8 == m && position9 == m) ||(position1 == m && position4 == m && position7 == m) ||
    (position2 == m && position5 == m && position8 == m) ||(position3 == m && position6 == m && position9 == m) ||
    (position1 == m && position5 == m && position9 == m) ||(position3 == m && position5 == m && position7 == m))
    {
    return true;
    }
return false;
}

/**
 * Checks if the board is full with no winner
 * @return true if the board is full with no winner, false otherwise boolean
 */
public static boolean isTie()
{
boolean tie = true;
Marker m = Marker.EMPTY;
if (position1 != m && position2 != m && position3 != m && 
    position4 != m && position5 != m && position6 != m && 
    position7 != m && position8 != m && position9 != m)
    {
    return tie;
    }
else
    {
    tie = false;
    return tie;
    }
}

/**
 * Mark the given position with the given marker
 * @param m The marker of the player given
 * @param pos The position that we are marking
 */

public static void markTheBoard(Marker m, int pos)
{
switch (pos)
    {
        case 1: 
            {
            position1 = m;
            break;
            }
        case 2: 
            {
            position2 = m;
            break;
            }
        case 3: 
            {
            position3 = m;
            break;
            }
        case 4: 
            {
            position4 = m;
            break;
            }
        case 5:
            {
            position5 = m;
            break;
            }
        case 6:
            {
            position6 = m;
            break;
            }
        case 7:
            {
            position7 = m;
            break;
            }
        case 8:
            {
            position8 = m;
            break;
            }
        case 9:
            {
            position9 = m;
            break;
            }

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're allowed to, you should implement the `toString()` method of the `Marker` enum to return the correct value. (Return `" "` if `this == EMPTY`, `"X"` if `this == X`, and so on.) To implement methods on enumerations, put a semicolon after the last member, then implement the method just as usual:

```
public enum Marker
{
    EMPTY, X, O;

    public String toString() { /* code here */ }
};
```

If you can't, then for each position you can check if the `Marker` is `EMPTY`, and if so print a space, and otherwise print the `Marker`.

Comment: So I tried the 2nd option you had. My instructor told me something similar to that, but it total flew over my head. I have `if (position1 == Marker.EMPTY) {position1 = " ";}` but I get incompatible types error.

Comment: You mustn't assign a space to the variable, because `Marker` and `String` are indeed not compatible. You should test this *before you print* the marker, and decide what to show based on that.

Comment: So I could add a method before `printBoard()` that checks if the positions are `EMPTY` , and if they are return a space? Thank you for all the help, still very new to CS.

Comment: Yes, I suggest that you create a method that accepts a `Marker` and returns the corresponding `String`. You'd display the result of this method instead of displaying the `Marker`.

Comment: OK, finally figured it out. I made a method that accepted the `Marker` and returned the string. Then called the method with respect to each position and it printed what was in those positions. Thank you so much. It looks so simple now that i have completed it.